# How to open for another user a graphical file explorer where 'Open in Terminal' works (22.04LTS)

Tags: command-line, nautilus, context-menu

I'm currently migrating from 18.04LTS to 22.04

How can I open for a differnt user than the one logged in

- a graphical file explorer
- within this file expolorer: open a command shell by mouse right click 'Open in Terminal'

The solution I used in 18.04 doesn't open a terminal anymore.

See also [Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" on 'Open in Terminal' (Ubuntu 22.04LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407041/failed-to-execute-child-process-dbus-launch-on-open-in-terminal-ubuntu-22-0)

Comment: No good practice. Have the other user log in.

Comment: Actually I have to login as myOtherUser, see shell from 18.04:
xhost +SI:localuser:myOtherUser
pkexec --user myOtherUser env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY nautilus
xhost -SI:localuser:myOtherUser - I need a convenient way to navigate through myOtherUesr's files and open a shell in case I need it. Worked with 18.04

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

Install dbus-launch (via `sudo apt install dbus-x11`)

```
#!/bin/sh
xhost +SI:localuser:myOtherUser
sudo --user myOtherUser env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY nautilus
xhost -SI:localuser:myOtherUser
```