# Does the "Files (Nautilus)" "Run Software" Button work?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, 22.04, nemo

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a VM. Inserting the "Guest Additions" ISO, I expected that the provided "Run Software" Button on the right side of the File manager would work.

Nautilus/Files was "backdropped" when pressing the button, but nothing happened:

[image]

Is this a new gnome feature or do I have to configure something for it to work? (Besides opening and executing it in a terminal the "classical" way)

Same procedure on Ubuntu 20.04 runs flawlessly (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the specific cause, but there seems to be a problem with the dbus-x11 package that is preventing the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run script from executing.  When I opened Nautilus through the terminal with root privileges and tried to install guest additions, I got the following error:  “g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed.”

A Google search led me a post where a user had received the same error message (but for a different issue). Here’s that post for reference:  [Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" on 'Open in Terminal' (Ubuntu 22.04LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407041/failed-to-execute-child-process-dbus-launch-on-open-in-terminal-ubuntu-22-0)

I figured it was worth a shot to install the dbus-x11 package to see if that would fix things, and it seems to have worked.  The script executed for me after installing the dbus-x11 package.

**Here are the specific steps that I took to fix the issue**
- *Open a terminal window and enter the following commands:*

sudo apt update

sudo apt install dbus-x11

sudo -H nautilus

After the Nautilus file manager opens, navigate to the VBox_Gas volume in the file manager, right click on VBoxLinuxAdditions.run, and select "Run as a Program."

This worked for me and I hope it works for others as well.

Comment: The dbus-11 package was installed. I just wondered why this "Run-Software" button does not work. Since I do not want to open any ui with sudo I can't accept your answer. I guess that sth has been started in the background (hence nautilus is loosing focus) but the expected authentication dialog  won't open (so I might have to rephrase my question)

Comment: Very strange that even after 9 month this problem still exists and no fix has surfaced