# Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/at-spi/bus: Permission denied, revisited

Tags: permissions, nautilus, dbus

Prerequisites, I installed:

```
sudo apt install dbus-x11
sudo apt-get install samba-common-bin
sudo mkdir /var/lib/samba/usershares
```

The following commands

```
xhost +SI:localuser:myOtherUser
sudo --user myOtherUser env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY nautilus
xhost -SI:localuser:myOtherUser
```

cause the following error:

```
(org.gnome.Nautilus:3806): dbind-WARNING **: 17:54:12.615: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/at-spi/bus: Permission denied
* Starting Nautilus Terminal
```

On a previous fresh install I already faced the above mentioned error, now it's there again on another Ubuntu 22.04.4 fresh install, see
[Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" on 'Open in Terminal' (Ubuntu 22.04LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407041/failed-to-execute-child-process-dbus-launch-on-open-in-terminal-ubuntu-22-0)
and
[Failed to execute child process "net" when entering Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024593/failed-to-execute-child-process-net-when-entering-nautilus)

Any ideas how I can get rid of the Permission denied error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

adding `NO_AT_BRIDGE=1` to the command worked for me:

```
sudo --user myOtherUser env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY NO_AT_BRIDGE=1 nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning but you can supress it, first create a script to wrap the dbus-launch command:

```
echo 'export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/dbus-launch-wrapper
echo '/usr/bin/dbus-launch "$@"' | sudo tee -a /usr/local/bin/dbus-launch-wrapper
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dbus-launch-wrapper
```

then modify your sudo command to use this wrapper script:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:myOtherUser
sudo --user myOtherUser env "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" "PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" nautilus
xhost -SI:localuser:myOtherUser
```

Comment: Sorry to ask again, after having created the wrapper script (file is existing: /usr/local/bin/dbus-launch-wrapper) and using the modified sudo command for the display the warning still is in my console. I think I'm using it somehow wrongly

Comment: I meant if I call the wrapper script with my sudo command script as parameter /usr/local/bin/dbus-launch-wrapper ./start-nauth.sh --> Warning in the console